# Steps to implement PageRank Algorithm on a local set of webpages

Tags: search-engine

I just completed a detailed theoretical mathematical study about the PageRank algorithm, I want to make a sample implementation to make some tests and play with it, supposing that I have a local set/folder full of a several webpages, representing a mini Web, I want to make a small software where I can make searches by implementing the PageRank algorithm (with some modifications in the algorithm) and make tests and simulations.

From what I know, I should crawl and index those web pages, then play with my ranking.

Is there a solution that provide me crawling and indexing and spares me the effort of working on them so I can focus on my main problem ?

Comment: So are you saying you want a local implementation of PageRank? Because that's top-secret Google sauce, not likely to be publicly available.

Comment: I'm aiming to implement the original version which is widely public and available

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_crawler#Open-source_crawlers ?

Comment: [Same question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23364499/1591669) on SO.